# How to create custom form element in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2

How can I in ZF2 create custom form element with custom validator? I want to create custom category picker that uses jQuery and content of this element should be rendered from phtml script. In ZF1 it was quite easy but in ZF2 I don't know from where to start.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A form element must implement a `Zend\Form\ElementInterface`. A default class is the `Zend\Form\Element` which you can use as a base form:

```
<?php
namespace MyModule\Form\Element;

use Zend\Form\Element;

class Foo extends Element
{
}
```

**CUSTOM VALIDATOR**

You can let the element directly assign a custom validator. Then you must implement the `Zend\InputFilter\InputProviderInterface`:

```
<?php
namespace MyModule\Form\Element;

use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputProviderInterface;
use MyModule\InputFilter\Bar as BarValidator;

class Foo extends Element implements InputProviderInterface
{
    protected $validator;

    public function getValidator()
    {
        if (null === $this->validator) {
            $this->validator = new BarValidator;
        }
        return $this->validator;
    }

    public function getInputSpecification()
    {
        return array(
            'name'       => $this->getName(),
            'required'   => true,
            'validators' => array(
                $this->getValidator(),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

**CUSTOM RENDERING**

At this moment it is a bit complex how Zend Framework handles the rendering of custom form element types. Usually, it just returns plain `<input type="text">` elements.

There is one option, then you have to override the `Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormElement` helper. It is registered as `formelement` and you must override this view helper in your custom module:

```
namespace MyModule;

class Module
{
    public function getViewHelperConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'invokables' => array(
                'formelement' => 'MyModule\Form\View\Helper\FormElement',
                'formfoo'     => 'MyModule\Form\View\Helper\FormFoo',
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Furthermore, every form element in Zend Framework 2 is rendered by a view helper. So you create a view helper for your own element, which will render the element's content.

Then you have to create your own form element helper (`MyModule\Form\View\Helper\FormElement`):

```
namespace MyModule\Form\View\Helper;

use MyModule\Form\Element;
use Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormElement as BaseFormElement;
use Zend\Form\ElementInterface;

class FormElement extends BaseFormElement
{
    public function render(ElementInterface $element)
    {
        $renderer = $this->getView();
        if (!method_exists($renderer, 'plugin')) {
            // Bail early if renderer is not pluggable
            return '';
        }

        if ($element instanceof Element\Foo) {
            $helper = $renderer->plugin('form_foo');
            return $helper($element);
        }

        return parent::render($element);
    }
}
```

As a last step, create your view helper to render this specific form element:

```
namespace MyModule\Form\View\Helper;

use Zend\Form\ElementInterface;
use Zend\Form\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Foo extends AbstractHelper
{
    public function __invoke(ElementInterface $element)
    {
        // Render your element here
    }
}
```

If you want to render a .phtml file for example for this form element, load it inside this helper:

```
namespace MyModule\Form\View\Helper;

use Zend\Form\ElementInterface;
use Zend\Form\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Foo extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $script = 'my-module/form-element/foo';

    public function render(ElementInterface $element)
    {
        return $this->getView()->render($this->script, array(
            'element' => $element
        ));
    }
}
```

It will render a `my-module/form-element/foo.phtml` and in this script you will have a variable `$element` which contains your specific form element.

Comment: I get Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to MyModule\Form\View\Helper\FormElement::render() must be an instance of MyModule\Form\View\Helper\ElementInterface, instance of Zend\Form\Element given

Comment: When i'm adding form element it is stil instance of Zend\Form\Element not Element\Foo, i'm adding something like this: `$this->add(array(
            'name' => 'category',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'MyModule\Form\Elemen\Foo',               
            ));`

Comment: @Maciej you are right, I made two mistakes: in the `FormElement` view helper you have to import the `ElementInterface` too, otherwise you get above warning. A second mistake was made in the view helper rendering your custom form element. Check the diff to see the differences, I think this should fix all problems: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13776839/revisions

Comment: Yes it's better but I still can't render element, probably I'm doing smoething wrong in form class:
`class MyForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct($name = null)
    {
        // we want to ignore the name passed
        parent::__construct('album');

        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'category',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'Element\Foo',               
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Category',
            ),            
        ));
    }
}`

Comment: For custom form elements it's the easiest way to use the FQCN (`MyModule\Form\Element\Foo`). Otherwise, instantiate them and add them like this: `$element = new \MyModule\Form\Element\Foo; $this->add($element)`. Above way assumes you are under the `Zend\Form` namespace, which will not work.

Comment: you cannot call the same render method passing a string, I think you meant $this->getView()->render()

Comment: Thanks heaps for this - so much harder and complex than ZF1. Can I ask if maybe the `Foo` view helper should have an `__invoke()` method? I was getting a `Function name must be a string` error in `MyModule/Form/View/Helper/FormElement.php` until I added it in?

Comment: It used to use the render() method. Now all form view helpers apparently had an overhaul so it doesn't work anymore. I edited the answer as render() should just be renamed to __invoke()

Comment: @JurianSluiman i need your help. my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949200/page-not-found-on-request-url-in-zend-2-framework-application/24952498